# How to change the attribute when only when the image loads?

Tags: jquery, image, load

```
var light ="http://www2.breakpoint.com.eg/site-content/themes/break/images/webdesign/webdesign_thumb3a.jpg";

    $('#lightbox').animate({
    top: '0px'
  }, 1000, function() {
    $("img#portimg").attr({
         src: 'images/loading.gif',
         style: 'margin-top:200px; width:31px; height:31px'
});

$("img#portimg").attr({
         src: light,
         style: 'margin-top:10px; width:620px; height:550px'
});
```

Using the code above, I'm showing a loading image that disappears once the the second image loads.

What i'm trying to do is to change the style only when the second image loads, because what happens is that the loading image appears but jquery neglects the first style and show the image with the second style.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, now that I better understand what you're trying to do.

Create another image (it doesn't have to be inserted into the DOM).
Set an onload handler for that image so you will know when it's loaded.
Set the src to that image to light.
When that image is loaded, call your code to change the attributes on "img#portimg".  Because the light image is now in the browser memory cache, it will display immediately.  Meanwhile, your loading image would have been displayed the whole time the light image was loading.

If you want to do this a less complicated way, then just preload the light image in your startup sequence so you don't have to wait for it with:

```
var myLightImage = new Image(light);   // create Image object in global variable
```

Then, it will be available instantly anytime you need it without any waiting.

Comment: actually it is a completion function, it starts after the animation.

Comment: What are you trying to do then?  You run an animation, then set the loading gif, then immediately set a different image.  That's not going to work.  If you want the loading gif to show for a particular amount of time, you have to set a timer for that time and only load the final image at that point.  It isn't clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to show the loading image until the main image loads :)

Comment: Just guessing here.  If you only want to set the new image when it's actually loaded, then you need to create a different img tag, set an load event handler for that img tag, set the src to your final image and in the load event handler for that img, you will know that the browser now has that image loaded and you can set the src on your other image tag to that image and it will show immediately.

Comment: OK, I edited my answer now that it's clearer what you were trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to use the `.load()` handler. I.e. something like

```
$("img#portimg").attr({
         src: 'images/loading.gif',
         style: 'margin-top:200px; width:31px; height:31px'
}).load(function(){...set your styles...});
```